# Get only text ( pure text, not <script> and others inside body ) using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-scraping

Im trying to parse and get all the text ( the one we actually see in the web browser ) , but im having some troubles with  and other tags inside the body.

I'm trying with pure javascript axios and cheerio.

```
  try {
    await axios.get(url).then((response)=> {
      html = cheerio.load(response.data).text();
    });
  }catch(e){
  };
```

Comment: What specific problem are you experiencing?

Comment: For example, i try to get all the text from a website using the function above, then store each word in an array, but i get stuffs like this inside the array:
                           
 'width="0px"',                                                   
 'style="display:nonevisibility:hidden"></iframe>\n',

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea. 
If your response contains valid html you can use jsdom and convert it to DOM object. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom After that you can get .textContent from this object.
Another option is this quick and dirty solution:

```
response.data.replace(/<[^>]+>/g,'')
```